# icon/image IN the title

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, favicon

I have just come across this website (http://helios.io) that has an icon IN the title.
Not a favicon, but next to the title text (on the right of it).

[image: are u a wizard?]

How was this achieved?

(worked in both Safari and Chrome)

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f680/index.htm

Comment: But it looks ugly on windows.

Comment: What does it look like on windows?

Comment: BTW I checked myself, and it is just a blank rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the Unicode character `U+1F680`.

You can find it here, using the handy Unicode Character Search:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=rocket&preview=entity

on your Mac, it's rendering used the built in emoji font - a preview is here:

http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/146/places/rocket